# recyclerview stick to a position with image zoom in/out animation while scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, android-scrollview, android-coordinatorlayout

When we scroll the view, the recyclerview sticks to a position and the image should zoom out with animation. Tried with the coordinator layout and toolbar as well but did not get success. Any help or suggestion would highly appreciable.

As you can see in GIF, how it is going.

[image]

Comment: add implementation code..

Answer (score 0):

```
    Finally get the solution with the help of MotionLayout. Here is my solution
    
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/root_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/back_screen_color_list"
        >
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_drawer_down"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/filter_search_layout_height"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/list_header_arrow_margin_top"
            android:gravity="center">
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_drawer_down"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/list_header_arrow_w_h"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/list_header_arrow_w_h"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_down_new"
                app:tint="@color/image_grey" />
        </LinearLayout>
    
    
        <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
            android:id="@+id/motionLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layoutDescription="@xml/chat_detail_anim"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout_drawer_down"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_detail_margin_left_right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_detail_margin_left_right"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_start_item">
    
    
    
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_group_image"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/big_img_width_height"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/big_img_width_height"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_dash_border_primary"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">
    
    
                <de.meinverein.app.view.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_group"
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="140dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    
                    />
    
    
            </RelativeLayout>
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_change_group_img"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/layout_group_image"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/layout_group_image"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_group_image"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/layout_group_image"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_two_users_1" />
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_group_image">
    
    
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/overlay_img_done_margin_top">
    
                    <de.meinverein.app.view.BoldFontTextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/linear_title_edit"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linear_title_edit"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:letterSpacing="0.018"
                        android:lineHeight="@dimen/line_height_17sp"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="Vereinstreffen"
                        android:textColor="@color/normal_text_color"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/title_text_28pt" />
    
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linear_title_edit"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_15dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="@dimen/padding_10dp">
    
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img_title_edit"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_overview_edit"
                            app:tint="@color/refs_btn" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
    
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear_participant"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/sort_item_row_height"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_title"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_30dp">
    
                    <!-- <RelativeLayout
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:gravity="center_vertical"
                         android:orientation="horizontal">-->
    
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_participant"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/tab_user"
                        app:tint="@color/refs_btn" />
    
                    <de.meinverein.app.view.BoldFontTextView
                        android:id="@+id/partipant_with_count"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_participant"
                        android:text="@string/participants"
                        android:textColor="@color/black_full"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/sort_row_txt_size" />
    
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layout_add_member"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_15dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="@dimen/padding_10dp">
    
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img_participant_edit"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_overview_add"
                            app:tint="@color/refs_btn" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
    
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyc_view_participants"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                android:background="@color/back_screen_color_list"
                />
    
            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_bottom"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:elevation="2dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:background="@drawable/list_bottom_shadow" />
    
            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_top"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:background="@drawable/list_top_shadow"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/recyc_view_participants"
    
                 />
    
        </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
    
        <include
            layout="@layout/line_progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/line_progress_bar_height"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>


Chat Detail anim class

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
        motion:duration="100"
        motion:motionInterpolator="linear">
        <OnSwipe
            motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/recyc_view_participants"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="bottom" />
    </Transition>

        <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/layout_group_image"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/big_img_width_height"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/big_img_width_height"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
             />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/img_change_group_img"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            motion:visibilityMode="normal"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/layout_group_image"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/layout_group_image"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_group_image"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/layout_group_image"
            motion:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.42" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/layout_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_group_image" />


        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/view_top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/recyc_view_participants"
            />



    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/layout_group_image"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/img_change_group_img"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            motion:visibilityMode="normal"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/layout_group_image"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/layout_group_image"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_group_image"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/layout_group_image"
            motion:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.42" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/layout_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_group_image" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/view_top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/recyc_view_participants"
            />

    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```